# How to use mac's default midi sequencer as midi out?

Tags: c++, macos, midi

I have been trying to play midi voices with rtmidi. I have sucessfully managed to link it and compile example programs. But unfortunately I can't see my snow leopards own midi sequencer as an output port. I also tried to open a midi output port using the coremidi library with no success.

How can I make rtmidi or another library send it's messages directly to the apple's own midi sequencer? 
Should I start a midi out server? If so, how can I do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I am trying to send these messages and play those voices to turn my computer keyboard in a musical instrument.

Answer (score 0):

So you are just interested in generating midi notes from the desktop keyboard and playing them back locally? You don't need to deal with output ports, RTMidi or anything like that. You would only need to that if you wanted to send message events to an external synth.

See this [PlaySoftMidi](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PlaySoftMIDI/Listings/main_cpp.html) Apple sample code for generating notes through the soft synth. If you want to load your own sound library (sound font 2 or DSL) search for "AUSampler" and "MusicDeviceMIDIEvent" - there are a few tutorials out there ([link](http://quickdekay.net/Software/Tutorials/CoreAudio/))

Comment: Thank you first of all. I have successfully compiled the example program. But the code seems to be very complicated. Sending midi out messages with rtmidi was way easier. Isn't there another way? Can't I just setup a virtual midi out server and let rtmidi recognize it?

Comment: It is not complicated code. There is a bit to set up the synth and then `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent` is used to send the midi notes to it. Perhaps you would be more comfortable working in Adobe AIR - a bit easier language. Or use an existing program - some hits here worth checking out: https://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+piano+midi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gbv=1&sei=niY5UKqIF7S30QHalYGICQ

Comment: I have finally decided to use python for my project and the fluidsynth library for python is just amazing. I can also load a decent soundfont and send noteon, noteoff messages with a couple of lines and it is also cross-platform.